# CSS Tablet vs Phone size

Tags: html, css

I have a row that displays the following in a **browser** (`any size`) and a **phone** (`1440 x 2560 portrait mode`):

[image]

But on a **tablet** (`1600 x 2560 portrait mode`), it displays the following:

[image]

I am able to fix it for the one, but then the other does not display as I would like.

**Question**

Is there a way in css to determine if I am on a **phone** or **tablet**? Or, is the a generic way I can handle this?

Thanks

**html**

```
<div class="person-job">
  <ion-row class="person-job-row">
    <p class="small-text-search small-text-by">by</p>
    <ion-col class="col-person-avatar">
      <ion-avatar item-right class="person-avatar" (click)="person(searchJobsParent.jobModel.person)">
        <img [src]="getPersonAvatar(searchJobsParent.jobModel)">
      </ion-avatar>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col class="col-person">
      <button ion-button (click)="person(searchJobsParent.jobModel.person)" color="primary" clear small>
    <div *ngIf="searchJobsParent.jobModel.person" class="icon-text icon-text-displayname">{{searchJobsParent.jobModel.person.displayName}}</div>
  </button>
      <br>
      <ion-note class="small-text-search person-last-online">
        Active {{searchJobsParent.jobModel.person.lastAccessDate | amTimeAgo:true}} ago
      </ion-note>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.col-person-avatar ion-avatar img {
    float: left;
}

.col-person.col {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.col {
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 1px;
    -webkit-flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

ion-avatar, ion-thumbnail {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1;
}

.contracted-content {
    max-width: 369px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Note**: `.contracted-content` is a higher level `<div>` that wraps the above code.

**UPADTE**

I think `@Kamuran Sönecek` is correct, its not a `media` screen widt issue. The reason I say this is because the devises I test this on are: `tablet: 8.40 inches 1600 x 2560 pixels` and `phone: 5.1-inch 2560x1440`. Also when I resize the browser on my desktop, not matter what size it is, I do not get the overlapping issue seen on the **tablet**.

Comment: Just a thought: it could be because of the browser, not the device.

Comment: It is running in a mobile app (ionic) on the browser, phone and tablet.

Comment: ur thing is not responsive. might want to take a look at media queries

Comment: CSS media queries will let you set different CSS rules depending on the width and/or height of the viewport.

Comment: I see, is that using something like? `@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {`

Comment: Yes, you definitely have to dig into media queries. Also, for things like this, --can-- help using flexbox, along with Autoprefixer for keeping compat safe.

Comment: Thanks for the advise

Comment: could you add ion-col and ion-avatar's css ?

Comment: this is not a media query issue, this is a cross browser problem.

Comment: @Kamuran Sönecek, thanks, I have updated the question above to include the css for: `add ion-col` and `ion-avatar`.

Comment: could you change this : `.col-person-avatar ion-avatar img {
    float: left;
}`  to this : `.col-person-avatar ion-avatar {
    float: left;
}` I think this problem is occured because of container.

Comment: @Kamuran Sönecek, I removed the `img` as you suggested, but still have the same issue (makes no difference).

Comment: I think `@Kamuran Sönecek` is correct, its not a `media` screen width issue issue. The reason I say this is because the devises I test this on are: `tablet: 8.40 inches 1600 x 2560 pixels` and `phone: 5.1-inch 2560x1440`. Also when I resize the browser on my desktop, not matter what size it is, I do not get the overlapping issue seen on the tablet.

Comment: @Richard If your tablet has android, you can debug it via chrome. There is a document : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) / [MQ Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) Your site doesn't seem to be responsive.

**Desktop**

[image]

**Phone**

[image]

**Sample:** *Desktop / Tablet / Phone*

```css
/*-- Common --*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  font: normal 14px/1.4 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 6px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.the-device {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.edge {
  background: #333;
}

.screen {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}


/*-- Mobile --*/

.edge {
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 40px 8px 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.screen:before {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70px;
}

.screen {
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
}

.screen:after {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  border-radius: 10em;
  content: " ";
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 -15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -41px;
  width: 30px;
}

.base {
  display: none;
}


/*-- Tablet --*/

@media all and (min-width: 700px) {
  .edge {
    padding: 50px 40px;
  }
  .screen {
    height: 600px;
    width: 450px;
  }
  .screen:before {
    height: 10px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    top: -30px;
    width: 10px;
  }
}


/*-- Desktop --*/

@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .the-device {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .edge {
    padding: 3%;
  }
  .screen {
    height: 600px;
    width: auto;
  }
  .screen:before,
  .screen:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .base {
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 15%;
  }
  .base:after {
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    content: " ";
    height: 15px;
    margin: 60px 0 0 -20%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Resize your browser viewport to see the device change. For best results, maximize the output window.</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="the-device">
    <div class="edge">
      <div class="screen"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="base"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, but I think `@Kamuran Sönecek` is correct, its not a `media` screen width issue issue. The reason I say this is because the devises I test this on are: `tablet: 8.40 inches 1600 x 2560 pixels` and `phone: 5.1-inch 2560x1440`. Also when I resize the browser on my desktop, not matter what size it is, I do not get the overlapping issue seen on the tablet.

Comment: did u try `!important`

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following media queries,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {//Your code}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {//Your code}
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {//Your code}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {//Your code}
```

Comment: If I resize my desktop browser, to any size there's no change. Also the tablet has a greater (1600) than the phone (1440). So it's not a media issue.

Comment: Try 'max-width' instead of 'min-width' in the above code.

Answer (score -2):

Please use CSS3 `@media` rule. For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    put your styles,its works only small screen
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think `@Kamuran Sönecek` is correct, its not a `media` screen width issue issue. The reason I say this is because the devises I test this on are: `tablet: 8.40 inches 1600 x 2560 pixels` and `phone: 5.1-inch 2560x1440`. Also when I resize the browser on my desktop, not matter what size it is, I do not get the overlapping issue seen on the tablet.